# Pass a no Static variable in a callback (LOOP)

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, binding, callback

what is the best way to pass a no static variable, in a callback, inside a loop ??
Ex: How to (fixing) a dynamic variable in a loop, and inject it into a CallBack

```
for (var i = 0, R = 0, C = 0; i < ItemPage.length; i++, C++) {
  $image.showPicture(PID++, 'M_Item_ItemSlot_Shader', 0, this.d2d2d2[0] + (this.ITDxy[0] * C), this.d2d2d2[1] + (this.ITDxy[1] * R), 100, 100, 255, 0);
  $image.setPictureTrigger(PID - 1, "Mouse Out", function(pictureId) {
    that.HoverOutItem(pictureId);
  });
  $image.setPictureTrigger(PID - 1, "Left Click", function(pictureId, i) {
    that.ClickItem(pictureId, i);
  }); // i whant pass i in this callback *****
  if ((i + 1) % 4 === 0) {
    C = -1, R++
  }
}
```

in this example if i pass `i`, its take only the `i` valur of the end loop.
How i can give static value to `i` and pass in the callback ?

Comment: How to (fixing) a dynamic variable in a loop, and inject it into a CallBack